# Why does jQuery remove parent <div>-elements by inserting new <div>-elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

By working on a project with Django I ran into a problem with my front-end.

I have made this quite simple Bootstrap grid and inserted with jQuery these yellow blocks that should be draggable and resizable (used jQuery UI Widgets for that) 
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGPYu.png)

My jQuery code (maybe a little messy ;) ):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var eventColumn = document.createElement("div");    // Create with DOM
    $(".employerMainRow").append(eventColumn)
    .css({ "background-color": "yellow", "height": "45px", "width": "40%", "margin-left":"40%"})
    .attr("class", "eventCol");
    $(".eventCol").resizable().resizable({ maxHeight: "45", containment: "parent",   // Handles left right and bottom right corner
    handles: 'e, w',
    // Remove height style
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css("height", '');}
}).draggable().draggable({
  axis: "x"
     });
  });
```

And my relevant html from template:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <h1 style="padding: 5px"> Arbeitsplanner: </h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2" style="border: double" > 
      <!--....some other grid content....-->
       </div>

      <!-- Main planner-table wrapper (right):-->
      <div class="col-lg-10" style="border: double">
           <!-- Header dates:-->
        <div style="background-color: grey; border: double"                                                                                                      id="mainContentWrapper" class="row">
        {% for columnDate in viewedDateColumns %}
        <div style="width: 20%; border: double" class="col-lg-2"><strong>{{columnDate}}</strong></div> 
        {%endfor%}
       </div>
          <!-- Main planner - main columnview: -->
      {% for employer in employers %}
       <div class="row employerMainRow" style="min-height: 45px; border: double; background-color: transparent; padding-right: 0px">

       </div>
       {%endfor%} 


          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

I blocked via jQuery that the yellow-divs can be resized in vertical direction (via handles). And this works, you can't resize it in that direction. But now the mouse keeps showing the mousepointer of resizing while hovering upon the bottom corner of the yellow divs. The really strange effect by using this is that by trying to resize in the vertical direction, one of the rows of the Bootstrap grid that I created just disappears. And the yellow div of that row shifts into the other row.

[(see the result also in this image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpoP0.png)

I just can't get why this happens and tried a couple of things by using the attributes offered by jQuery UI but it changes nothing.

Is there something I'm doing fundamentally wrong in my code that makes this happen? Is there something to prevent it?

Hope the problem/idea is clear. (I would like to give a demo-site but with django that's a little tricky, when it is still online maybe: https://rothe-plana-sv8930.c9users.io/)

**edit:** I think I can narrow down the fundamental problem a little bit. On running the template with my jQuery-code, I found out [(source-code view of firefox)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pULIO.png) that jQuery UI just deleted the row-divs that I created from the beginning by loading the page itself. (No resizing involved yet). Note that I had to put the yellow eventCol into these "row"-elements so depending on where I insert things with jQuery, the parent element seems to get removed completely.

Is there a gerneral reason for that?

Comment: I've tried the demo link and I think this is the problem. As soon as you start resizing the first block, its starting position is reset to the initial position at display. If you can capture the current position of the div before the resize operation and add that to your css in the resize function, it should fix your issue. For the top div, the attribute `left` is being set to zero as soon as the resize starts. It's not happening with the other div. Change the color of the top div to red and see.

Comment: @RaghuramKasyap Thank you for your comment. May you please specify what you mean by "the initial position at display". The problem is that these are nested div´s, so in terms of this one; the position inside the parent is not relative to anything than the parent. So position is just defined by the margin-left attribute. So dependent on what happens with the specific rows, the yellow divs will be affected.

Comment: For the top div, the attribute left is being set to zero as soon as the resize starts. It's not happening with the other div.